# How to properly include library path and other flags in extconf.rb for SWIG?

Tags: ruby, binding, swig

Suppose I were to compile a C file with command

```
g++ a.cpp  -I/usr/local/gr/include -L/usr/local/gr/lib -lGR -lm -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/gr/lib
```

How would I define the extconf.rb file in SWIG so that it doesn't ignore the linker paths?
This is my current extconf.rb file.

```
require 'mkmf'
system('swig -c++ -ruby example.i') or abort
$CXXFLAGS += " -I/usr/local/gr/include -L/usr/local/gr/lib -lGR -lm -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/gr/lib "
create_makefile('example')
```

It ignores the linker flags with the error

```
clang: warning: -lGR: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -lm: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: -Wl,-rpath,/usr/local/gr/lib: 'linker' input unused [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-L/usr/local/gr/lib' [-Wunused-command-line-argument]
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing almost nothing about ruby or the build system here it seems likely you want to change it to be this:

```
require 'mkmf'
system('swig -c++ -ruby example.i') or abort
$CXXFLAGS += " -I/usr/local/gr/include "
$LDFLAGS += " -L/usr/local/gr/lib -lGR -lm -rpath,/usr/local/gr/lib "

create_makefile('example')
```

Because typically build systems split compiling and linking into two separate phases, with compile flags coming from variables named `CCFLAGS`/`CXXFLAGS` (for C and C++ compilers respectively) and linker flags coming from `LDFLAGS` by convention.

The error message you see from clang indicates that it's being called as a compiler and telling you that when just compiling (and not linking) it ignores the extra options you have given it that only apply to linking.

You may or may not need to remove the `-Wl` part of the argument as I've done here - the decision for that depends on whether you're calling a linker (/usr/bin/ld normally) directly, or using clang/gcc as a linker.